# How to add and use an external js file in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, file, external

I am trying to add an external javascript file to Codeigniter application.

I have placed my external js file in the "projectname/js/" folder.

Below is the script tag src in my view page.
src="http://localhost/needpcbcodeigniter/js/registration.js">

But I am getting a "Not found" error for the js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably this is because the apache mod_rewrite is dealing with the **js** folder as a codeigniter controller name (as if you're calling http://localhost/projectname/index.php/js/registration.js)

Check your .htaccess to make sure it doesn't redirect when a valid filename is requested. Check it [here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/)

Comment: i am a newbie to codeignitor,where can i find the htaccess file in the installation folder?

Comment: You can't find it in the CI installation files..Create a new file and name it .htaccess in your project root manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an external javascript file to codeigniter in assets folder.

You should check some following steps :-

1) first fix your project `base_url` which is set in `application/config/config.php` like-

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/'`

2) create a folder(e.g: js) in `assets` folder(at root of folder) for save all javascript files(e.g : registration.js).

3) on final step where you want to  use javascript file use code like this-

`<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/js/registration.js"></script>`